# SignalR and Nop Commerce Plugin

Tags: signalr, nopcommerce

I'm attempting to get SignalR working in a Nop Commerce plugin. I've installed the NuGet package and have written my Startup class but the Startup class is never being called. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Nop.Plugin.Misc.CAImport.Infrastructure.Startup))]
namespace Nop.Plugin.Misc.CAImport.Infrastructure
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Nop 3.50 and it is necessary to add NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 2.1.0 in order to trigger the Startup class.